# Transition between views, best practice

Tags: qt, qml

As in the object I ask you to indicate me / to link a good example in order to pass between different QML views in a test application.

The question is not so simple as it seems because I found several example but:

1. I found several example with a child sub-QML loaded / done visible in a parent QML but is not what I am searching for (I want a real transaction, by closing a QML view and opening one other);
2. I would do it in the best way, by applying the best practice.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide [mcve] of the real issue you want to implement

Comment: Is not the same opinion of @David K. Hess; without any example, he understood exactly what I mean and was able to give me a perfect solution. Thanks anyway for the reply (and maybe also for the negative score to my question).

Comment: I didn't downvote but: you have several solutions you know of so why not post the code for it? Then you can say, "this does something similar to what I want to do, but X and Y are missing" or "this does what I want, but is there a better way"? The question as it stands _is_ broad, and in my experience that usually results in the OP responding to any answers with "but this doesn't do what I want", because they never put that information into the question to begin with. So it wastes time and is less useful for people searching for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use StackView. It is the main QML control designed for managing multiple views and the transitions between them.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html